# Can the initramfs image use a compression format other than gzip?

Tags: linux, compression, initrd, gzip

Can the initramfs image be compressed by a method other than gzip, such as lzma?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. I use in-kernel initrd and it offers at least the following methods:

- None (as it is compressed with kernel)
- GZip
- BZip
- LZMA (possibly [zen](http://zen-kernel.org/)-only)

You can use it on external file and with LZMA (at least [on Ubuntu](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/CustomizeLiveInitrd)).

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initrd) states that Linux kernel supports gzip, bzip and lzma (depending, of course, what algorithms are compiled in).

Comment: does it must be "in-kernel" initrd (and what do you actually means by in-kernel) ? what if I have external file of initrd?

Comment: I would be very surprised if it used different files. As in what it actually means - you can build-in initrd in kernel just as you can build-in modules. I have / on LVM so I need to have initrd script - and the easiest way for me is to build it into kernel.

Comment: sorry but the 'initrd' in this question is actually an initramfs file or a filesystem that initially loaded by kernel, or the file which usually pointed by grub like this `initrd /boot/initramfs-2.6.33.3-85.fc13.i686.img`, maybe I used wrong term (I edited the question)?

Comment: As I stated in edit - yes at least in Ubuntu. I'd be very surprised if it hadn't work. You haven't used the wrong term but I said what 1) I have experience with 2) what I found (that Ubuntu do support it) 3) what I expect. Anyway - why not just try it.

Comment: ok I tried it, it confirmed the kernel can load initramfs with lzma compression, I must compile the kernel using `CONFIG_RD_LZMA=y`. but it will KP if the compression parameter is other than default, for example if i try `lzma -e -9 -z` for initramfs image it will leads to KP.

Answer (score 3):

**v4.15 `INITRAMFS_COMPRESSION_*`**

These kernel config options determine if compression is enabled or not.

A quick:

```
git grep INITRAMFS_COMPRESSION_
```

on the kernel tree leads to:

```
usr/Kconfig:134:config INITRAMFS_COMPRESSION_NONE
usr/Kconfig:145:config INITRAMFS_COMPRESSION_GZIP
usr/Kconfig:155:config INITRAMFS_COMPRESSION_BZIP2
usr/Kconfig:168:config INITRAMFS_COMPRESSION_LZMA
usr/Kconfig:181:config INITRAMFS_COMPRESSION_XZ
usr/Kconfig:194:config INITRAMFS_COMPRESSION_LZO
usr/Kconfig:206:config INITRAMFS_COMPRESSION_LZ4
```

Comment: I believe this is only relevant for a "built in initramfs" (see https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/d4e9056daedca3891414fe3c91de3449a5dad0f2/usr/Kconfig#L104). For most uses of initramfs (e.g. at boot time on Debian/Ubuntu) an external file is used. For that way of working, the CONFIG_RD_ options apply

Answer (score 2):

You can see what compressions are supported for initramfs with:

```
zgrep CONFIG_RD_ /proc/config.gz
# or
grep CONFIG_RD_ /usr/src/linux/.config
```

Comment: The initramfs options are apparently called: `INITRAMFS_COMPRESSION_`, I think `CONFIG_RD_` are for initrd?
 https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/429880/32558

Comment: Ohh! Thanks for zgrep! =)