# Why initrd size is not fixed?

Tags: debian, ubuntu, initramfs, compression, initrd

After **update-initramfs -c -k KERNELVERSION**(I didn't do any change and just type this command), the initrd will always has different size with the previous initrd.
And this situation happen on Debian 11 and Ubuntu 20.04.
Does initrd has different compression method each time?

Answer (score 0):

Why would it be the same?

1. It includes kernel modules which see updates all the time and thus may change in size
2. It includes various system libraries and binaries which also change

Comment: @PhilipCouling sorry, I meant "binaries".  I've just fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Initramfs is typically compressed with gzip [or other](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/2225/20140).  It's possible that some meta data is changing between invocations.  Because of the way compression works changing the content can change the size.

Beyond that there are things in initramfs that are dependent on your system.  This can include entries from /etc/database and /etc/crypttab.  If these files change without updating initramfs it can change the size next time you do.

Its also possible for kernel modules to be upgraded. I'd expect these to trigger a rebuild of initramfs by the package manager (Doug) but perhapse not.